# Multiple Jenkin execution results in replacing the result values in XRay issue

Tags: jenkins, junit, jira-xray, x-ray

I am trying to integrate Junit, Jenkins with Xray such that post automation it has to update the Xray test cases. I have specified the dedicated Test Execution value so that after every execution, same issue needs to be updated with the Xray results. But here after each execution, previous results are been replaced with the newer results.

As in say i have 3 test cases that runs as part of Test Execution type. Post execution, you can see the 3 test cases listed but execution details will be overridden (replaced)

Is there any way to configure so that i can preserve all the test runs that are being executed?

Answer (score 1):

Xray allow you to import the test execution results and either create new test executions (creating a new test execution each time a result is uploaded linked to the test) or update already created test executions (always replacing the results of the executions with the new ones).

Depending on the Jira version that you have (Server/Cloud) you can find how to do it here:

- Cloud: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Jenkins+pipeline+integration#Jenkinspipelineintegration-CreatenewTestExecution
- Server: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Jenkins+pipeline+integration#Jenkinspipelineintegration-CreatenewTestExecution

API documentation on how to import execution results is available here:

- Server: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST
- Cloud: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST